# Failed to update access database

Tags: c#

this is my items class add button method

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BL.CLSItems itemsADE = new BL.CLSItems();

    try
    {
        itemsADE.EditItem(Convert.ToInt32(itemId.Text), 
        itemBarcode.Text, itemName.Text, itemGroup.Text, 
        itemCompany.Text, itemPlace.Text, 
        Convert.ToInt32(itemPrice.Text), 
        Convert.ToInt32(itemquantity.Text), 
        Convert.ToInt32(itemLimit.Text), 
        Convert.ToInt32(itemMaxDiscount.Text), 
        Convert.ToInt32(itemprofit.Text));
        MessageBox.Show("تم تعديل البيانات بنجاح", "تعديل", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        dataGridRefresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "خطأ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

thismy CLSItems Class

```
public void EditItem(int itemId, string itemBarcode, 
     string itemName, string itemGroup, string itemCompany, 
     string itemPlace, int itemPrice, int itemquantity, 
     int itemLimit, int itemMaxDiscount, int itemprofit)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer Dal = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();

    Dal.open();
   string procedure = @"update Items
       (itemBarcode,itemName,itemGroup,itemCompany,
        itemPlace,itemPrice,itemquantity,itemLimit,itemMaxDiscount,
        itemprofit)values
       (@itemBarcode,@itemName,@itemGroup,@itemCompany,
        @itemPlace,@itemPrice,@itemquantity,@itemLimit,@itemMaxDiscount,
        @itemprofit) where itemId=@itemId";

    //string procedure = @"update Items set 
    //itemBarcode=@itemBarcode, itemName=@itemName,  
    //itemGroup=@itemGroup, 
    //itemCompany=@itemCompany, itemPlace=@itemPlace,        
    //itemPrice=@itemPrice, 
    //itemquantity=@itemquantity, itemLimit=@itemLimit, 
    //itemMaxDiscount=@itemMaxDiscount, itemprofit=@itemprofit 
    //where itemId=@itemId ";

    OleDbParameter[] param = new OleDbParameter[11];
    param[0] = new OleDbParameter("@itemBarcode", OleDbType.VarChar);
    param[0].Value = itemBarcode;
    param[1] = new OleDbParameter("@itemName", OleDbType.VarChar);
    param[1].Value = itemName;
    param[2] = new OleDbParameter("@itemGroup", OleDbType.VarChar);
    param[2].Value = itemGroup;
    param[3] = new OleDbParameter("@itemCompany", OleDbType.VarChar);
    param[3].Value = itemCompany;
    param[4] = new OleDbParameter("@itemPlace", OleDbType.VarChar);
    param[4].Value = itemPlace;
    param[5] = new OleDbParameter("@itemPrice", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[5].Value = itemPrice;
    param[6] = new OleDbParameter("@itemquantity", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[6].Value = itemquantity;
    param[7] = new OleDbParameter("@itemLimit", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[7].Value = itemLimit;
    param[8] = new OleDbParameter("@itemMaxDiscount", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[8].Value = itemMaxDiscount;
    param[9] = new OleDbParameter("@itemprofit", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[9].Value = itemprofit;
    param[10] = new OleDbParameter("@itemId", OleDbType.Integer);
    param[10].Value = itemId;
    Dal.excuteCommand(procedure, param);
    Dal.close();
}
```

this is my DataAccessLayer class

```
public void excuteCommand(string procedure,OleDbParameter[] param)
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = procedure;
    command.Connection = accessConnection;
    if (param!=null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

the problem is when i try to update my access data base i receive this message

> input string was not in a correct format

what is the problem? in my code? 
in my data base?

```
itemId/int,itemBarcode/Text ,itemName/Text,itemPlace/Text ,itemPrice/currency,itemquantity/int,itemLimit/int,itemMaxDiscount/int,itemprofit/currency
```

i used this statement and same problem

```
string procedure = "update Items set itemBarcode=@itemBarcode, itemName=@itemName, itemGroup=@itemGroup, itemCompany=@itemCompany, itemPlace=@itemPlace, itemPrice=@itemPrice, itemquantity=@itemquantity, itemLimit=@itemLimit, itemMaxDiscount=@itemMaxDiscount, itemprofit=@itemprofit where itemId=@itemId ";
```

Comment: Apart from the wrong syntax, the query has 16 fields, you have only 14 parameter placeholders and you supply only 11 parameters. I suggest to use line breaking to have a better picture of your code.

Comment: i didn't want to update the three other fields

Comment: Try to replace the VarChar with VarWChar. I think you have Unicode characters in those values. Also check if the underlying datatable columns have the exact datatype as you have specified in the parameters type.

Comment: same problem after changing to VarWChar

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the update code? If any of those string conversions you make before calling the EditItem method, fail because the string is not a valid integer, you get the exception Invalid String Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a lot of variables to the EditItem method and you blindly call Convert.ToInt32 on the input textboxes. But if any of those textboxes contains a value that cannot be converted to an integer, you get the Invalid String Format exception.
(For example a blank input is an invalid integer and triggers the exception)

You should instead check if the input is valid as integer using the Int32.TryParse

```
int id;
if(!Int32.TryParse(itemId.Text, out id))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for ID field! Please write a valid integer");
    return;
}
int price;
if(!Int32.TryParse(itemPrice.Text, out price))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for the price field! Please write a valid integer");
    return;
}
.... and so on for all integer values


itemsADE.EditItem(id,itemBarcode.Text, itemName.Text, itemGroup.Text, 
                  itemCompany.Text, itemPlace.Text, 
                  price, ......);
```

Final notes.

The UPDATE statement requires this syntax:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname> = <value> WHERE <keyfield> = <keyvalue>
```

Are you sure to use a price field of type integer? Usually these fields are defined with the decimal data type to correctly handle a money value.

Comment: thank you very much the problem was in itemprice it double not int

Comment: Well, that explain the problem. However, remember that double values are not good for money data. They loose precision and your calculation with these values will never be correct. Use a decimal field

Answer (score 0):

```
update Items(...) values (....)
```

is **not a correct SQL update syntax**. (I think you were confused with the `insert` syntax?)

The correct syntax is what you have commented out:

```
update Items 
set 
itemBarcode=@itemBarcode, 
itemName=@itemName, 
itemGroup=@itemGroup, 
itemCompany=@itemCompany, 
itemPlace=@itemPlace, 
itemPrice=@itemPrice, 
itemquantity=@itemquantity, 
itemLimit=@itemLimit, 
itemMaxDiscount=@itemMaxDiscount, 
itemprofit=@itemprofit 
where itemId=@itemId
```

Comment: i used this and same problem "            //string procedure = "update  Items set itemBarcode=@itemBarcode, itemName=@itemName, itemGroup=@itemGroup, itemCompany=@itemCompany, itemPlace=@itemPlace, itemPrice=@itemPrice, itemquantity=@itemquantity, itemLimit=@itemLimit, itemMaxDiscount=@itemMaxDiscount, itemprofit=@itemprofit where itemId=@itemId ";
"

Comment: It's hard to read code in the comments, please update your question with the correct format and we'll see what's the problem then.